# Run an executable concatenated with data?

Tags: linux, binary, executable

This is a bit confusing. I have a linux executable that I do not have the source code for that is used to view a certain type of proprietary data.

I'd like to have a copy of the executable that opens viewing one particular file. Normally I'd just write a script that launches the executable with the right arguments, but the trouble is that I need to deliver the functionality as a *single file*. I can't have the executable and the data file separate.

The only way I see to do this is to concatenate the data file with the executable, along with a small self-written executable to do the magic. The trouble with this is that I have no idea how to write the magic executable, or if what I propose is even possible.

Comment: What operating system(s) do you have to target?

Comment: Linux. Sorry, I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some linux installers are distributed as shell scripts that work something like this:

The script itself is executable, and it contains all of its associated binaries, data files, *etc*. as [here documents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document), probably first [base64 encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).  When the script runs, it extracts the components, then executes or installs them as appropriate.

Will a scheme like this work for you?

Comment: Thank you. It never occurred to me to store the binaries as strings, but that seems to be the most simple approach. Thanks to Thomas Carpenter as well for his similar suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a program with the data, a binary representation of the program, and running the app saves the app, data and executes the app... waits for app to terminate, then cleans up app & data.

Save the data & program as C-strings... you can probably write a script to generate code that defines a char array one byte at a time.